# Notifications don't show in action centre

Tags: windows-10-mobile, nokia-lumia-830

Whenever I get a toast, I see the notification icon at the top. But when I pull down the action centre, they disappear, and I can't see what app they come from of there were multiple notifications. Ive tried rebooting, notifications are turned on, and not set to be dismissed automatically, and it happens with all notifications. How do I solve this problem?